# Splitting String into array and display it by chunk

Tags: php, string

```
foreach($files as $file) {
    $xname = basename($file['name'],'.jpg');
    $tmp = preg_split("/[\s,-]+/",$xname,-1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($tmp);
    echo "</pre>";
```

here is the example string "LR-147-TKW FLOWER RECT MIRROR FRAME"

I have this line of code that splits my string to arrays. What i want it do is to get the first  3 words which is "LR-147-TKW" and store it to a variable. how can i achieve this?
my array output is this `0] => BR
    [1] => 139
    [2] => TKW
    [3] => DRESSER
    [4] => BUFFET
    [5] => MIRROR`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), here are some examples:

```
<?php 
$str = 'LR-147-TKW FLOWER RECT MIRROR FRAME';
$parts = explode(' ',$str);

print_r($parts);
/*
Array
(
    [0] => LR-147-TKW
    [1] => FLOWER
    [2] => RECT
    [3] => MIRROR
    [4] => FRAME
)

*/

$serial_parts = explode('-',$parts[0]);
print_r($serial_parts);
/*
Array
(
    [0] => LR
    [1] => 147
    [2] => TKW
)

*/


$full = array_merge($serial_parts,$parts);
print_r($full);
/*
Array
(
    [0] => LR
    [1] => 147
    [2] => TKW
    [3] => LR-147-TKW
    [4] => FLOWER
    [5] => RECT
    [6] => MIRROR
    [7] => FRAME
)

*/
?>
```

Comment: Yeah i already tried that the question now is how to display it in such a manner that "LR-147-TKW" as the SKU number and "FLOWER RECT MIRROR FRAME" becomes its product name?

Answer (score 0):

this actually does the trick for you current input. $tmp will contain LR-147-TKW after you execute this line of code:

```
list($tmp) = explode(' ', $input);
```

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => LR-285-TKW
    [1] => STAIRS
    [2] => CABINET
    [3] => LEFT
) how will i contain array[1] -array [3] in one a variable?

Comment: what do you mean??? I'm not quite sure what you are asking. if you want to store all the other values in the array in avriables you could do something like this list($first, $second, $third, $fourth) = explode(' ', $input); meaning that the first element of the array is stored in $first, the second in $second etc... if that is what you are asking. see the list specification on http://www.php.net/list

Answer (score 0):

How about using [`explode`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) :

```
$arr = explode(' ',$file);
echo arr[0];
```

using `preg_split` is a bit of overkill for such a simple task...

If you want to avoid the array, it can be done using [strpos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [substr](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
$pos = strpos($file, ' ');
echo substr('abcdef', 0, $pos);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `preg_split("/[\s,-]+/",...` splits your string where ever a comma, minus or space occurs. Change it to `preg_split("/[\s,]+/",...)` and it should give you the correct array.

Note that if you do that, your function won't split words like `WELL-SPOKEN`. It will become one entry in your array.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your string has same pattern.

$str = "LR-147-TKW FLOWER RECT MIRROR FRAME";

$str1 = explode(' ',$str);

echo $str1[0];

Answer (score -1):

add to your code:

```
$tmp = array_slice($tmp,0,3);
```